# Drools - Ability to define rules at runtime?

Tags: dynamic, runtime, rules, drools

It is possible to define rules dynamically completely at runtime ? 
Also change the ruleset at runtime.

For example,

```
at time = t_1 the ruleset is { R1, R2, R3 } 
at time = t_2 the ruleset is { R1, R3, R4 } 
.....
```

R1, R2 are rules that are defined at runtime.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, Drools is completely dynamic. You can add/remove/replaces rules at runtime. All the existing sessions are automatically updated in order to keep consistency. Check the documentation/javadoc:

http://www.jboss.org/drools/documentation

And here you can see some integration tests:

[DynamicRulesTest.java](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/main/drools-test-coverage/test-compiler-integration/src/test/java/org/drools/mvel/integrationtests/DynamicRulesTest.java)

Comment: Is there a equivalent for Drools 7+ (I am using 7.27.0.Final). The code you point to uses internal classes/methods (`KnowledgeBase` and `KnowledgeSession`), while the `KieBase` class does not have a `addPackage` method.

Comment: Does anyone have the power to resurrect that lost file, DynamicRulesTest.java?

Comment: All the links from your answer are currently broken

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation and check out the tests about "KnowledeAgent" to see what you can do and how you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

In Drools 5 you just need to change KnowledgeBase, it will keep the KnowledgeSession implicitly up to date. That is what the integration tests tell you. You actually do not need a KAgent for that.