# Inserting rules dynamically into camel-drools component

Tags: dynamic, runtime, apache-camel, rules, drools

Is there a way to inserting (and removing) rules at runtime using the Drools-Camel component ? 
According to these two you can only insert facts.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-2804

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/master/drools-camel/src/test/java/org/drools/camel/component/CamelEndpointActionInsertTest.java

If there is no support for doing this in the drools-camel component what other options are there for inserting and removing rules at runtime.

thanks.

Comment: Please add comment when you post the same questions in other places as well. See http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Inserting-rules-dynamically-into-camel-drools-component-td5681880.html

Comment: This question seems to have the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422106/drools-ability-to-define-rules-at-runtime?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for this date, I couldn't find a way to achieving this in camel-drools component.

Answer (score 1):

drools-camel uses drools-spring. drools-spring can use a `KnowledgeAgent` spring configuration to get its `KnowledgeBase` from Guvnor. Guvnor can be used to add or remove rules.