# Dynamic loading of rules in DROOLS

Tags: java, drools

I am new to drools. I just want to understand how to dynamically update rules at run time. 
Considering [Drools - Ability to define rules at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422106/drools-ability-to-define-rules-at-runtime)

I wrote a code:

```
 while(true){
    session = fetchStatefulSession();//Some method to get drools session
    system.out.println("enter text");
    //Some code to read input
    session.fireAllrules();
 }
```

Now by the time I give input I have updated .drl rules file. Even after that the result is same on,

```
 session.fireAllrules();
```

as it was earlier. That is the changes in rules are not reflected.

I am not sure is this proper way to use, dynamic loading of rules. Please suggest me

Thanks
Chakri

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only getting the session which is still using the same .drl file. Your code needs to include loading the .drl files as well.

```
knowledgeBuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(rulesFile, YourClass.class), ResourceType.DRL);
```

But still I doubt it will work or not because loading files at run time is very prone to error and difficult to maintain.

Comment: Thanks Mawia, But isn't that high availability expected business applications update their business logic flow through this? Or they just stop the server-> updated rules-> and go to start server? Please help me understand how drools is utilised to change business flow Thanks-Chakri

Comment: If you need dynamic drools then go for Drools Guvnor. It is complicated to setup the whole thing in Guvnor but if this is the exact requirement, it may be useful.

Comment: **KnowledgeAgent** can continually update the rules as Guvnor changes them by releasing them.