# File location when loading rules dynamically in Drools 6

Tags: java, drools

I'm using `KieFileSystem.write` to load a .drl file dynamically. Does it matter the location where the file is written within the virtual file system? All tutorials I found online seem to suggest `src/main/resources/myRules.drl` and as far as I can tell rules written to other locations (say `myRules.drl`) are not being loaded.

I think I read somewhere that Drools scans the classpath for .drl files. Does that mean it also loads files from the physical file system when a virtual one is explicitly created or does the virtual replaces the physical one?

Is there any detail explanation how the rule loading works?

I'm not using maven for my project BTW.

Comment: maybe this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542610/drools-6-0-dynamically-load-rules-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

The rule is simple. You need to explicitly tell `drools` what type of resource you are trying to load. [`ResourceFactory`](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.1/javadocs/org/drools/io/ResourceFactory.html) supports classpath resources, streams, files, etc.

**Example**

Here is an example on how you can obtain `KieBase` instance using custom file resources.

```
List<Resource> resources = Arrays.asList(
    // loads file from "real" filesystem
    ResourceFactory.newFileResource("example.drl")
);

KieServices kieServices = Factory.get();
KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
resources.forEach(kfs::write);
KieContainer kieContainer =
    kieServices.newKieContainer(
        kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());

KieBaseConfiguration config =
    Factory.get().newKieBaseConfiguration();
KieBase base = kieContainer.newKieBase(config);
```