# Example use of Drools fluent API to change rules on the fly

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I came along the Drools fluent API which, as far as I understand, allows Rules to be added/edited/deleted from working memory at runtime.

The documentation mentions it here without going into details:

http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/droolsjbpm-introduction-docs/html/ch02.html#d0e124

Does anyone have example code on how to use this API?

I am specially interested in adding/changing/deleting rules at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that section was speaking more to the fact that they have a programmatic way to create rules.  I was under the impression that the "fluent" part referred the their use of the builder pattern that allowed you to string methods together in the same way a rule would appear.

But yes, you are able to change/edit/delete rules dynamically for a particular KnowledgeBase.  An example can be found in their [sample integration tests](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/compiler/integrationtests/DynamicRulesTest.java), or consult the [KnowledgeBase docs](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.1/javadocs/org/drools/KnowledgeBase.html#addKnowledgePackages%28java.util.Collection%29) - particularly the `addKnowledgePackages(Collection<KnowledgePackage> kpackages)` and `removeRule(String packageName, String ruleName)` functions.

I suppose you can combine the DescrFactory with the rule addition/creation.  I'm not really able to find a public API anywhere that will help you with how to use it, and it's in the drools-compiler dependency, so I'm not certain that there will be one published as much of that artifact is meant for drools internal use.

There is also another related S/O discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422106/drools-ability-to-define-rules-at-runtime).

Comment: In fact I wrote "fluent API", and I meant, like you said, "programmatic way to create rules". Thanks for your answer and your reading between my lines :)